# REACT router not working inside child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am new to REACT. I have created a REACT project which has three routes as show below

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
<Route path="/list" render={()=> (
  <UserList store={store} />
)} />
<Route path="/create" render={({history})=> (
  <CreateUser store={store} history={history} />
)} />
```

But when i move the Route to a child component, it stopped working, I moved the code below to my listcomponent.

```
<Route path="/create" render={({history})=> (
  <CreateUser store={store} history={history} />
)} />
```

After this the link redirects to /create but the component is not getting loaded.

help much appreciated.

Entire App Component

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <br />
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link> | 
          <Link to="/list">User List</Link> | 
          <Link to="/create">Add User</Link> | 
        </div>
        <br />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/list" render={()=> (
          <UserList store={store} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/create" render={({history})=> (
          <CreateUser store={store} history={history} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" render={({history, match}) => (
          <EditUser store={store} history={history} match={match} />
        )}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now when i move the CreateUser route to my editUser component like shown below.

```
render() {
    return <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.updateUser}>
            <input type="text"name="username" ref={(input)=>this.usernameTxt = input} placeholder="Username" /><br />
            <input type="text"name="location" ref={(input)=>this.locationTxt = input} placeholder="Location" /><br />
            <button>Update user</button>
        </form>
        <Route path="/create" render={({history})=> (
            <CreateUser store={store} history={history} />
        )} />
    </div>
}
```

Now it will stop showing the createform

Comment: can you show the entire component where the nested route is placed?

Comment: @azium i have modified the code to show what is going wrong with my application.

Comment: @Arun. Is there any reason for moving the route of createuser to myedit component.Please see my below answer.you dont need to pass these props to the component.By default this will be added by the react router...

Answer (score 0):

> You dont have to pass the history prop to the component of the
>   router.By default this prop will be passed by the react router.

I used redux as my store in this following example.You dont have to pass the store  to  every component to access the store.Just add the provider with your store as the prop to the root of your component.

For working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/9jvz19949r